# Drools Complex Rule Advice on Accumulating Facts

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, drools-fusion

I need some advice on how to write a rule for the following case. First, here are my facts:

```
SessionClock($now : new Date(getCurrentTime()))

ClickEvent( $userId : userId, $productId : productId, $event : "FAVORITE" / "REMOVE_FAVORITE" )

Product($id : id, $endDate : endDate)

Purchase ( $userId : userId, $purchasedProducts : purchasedProducts )
```

where `purchasedProducts` is a `List` of:

```
PurchasedProduct( $id : id, $price : price)
```

Now I would like to send a notification everytime at a particular hour:

1. Today is the endDate of a product and
2. User has favorited but hasn't unfavorited the product (from `ClickEvent`) and
3. User hasn't bought the product (from `Purchase`) and
4. Include all such products in one notification (basically I need to `collect` products)

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's all a bit hazy. What is the format of the endDate, e.g., is it a Date with h:m:s=0:0:0, i.e. midnight? Are these ClickEvent facts kept since the beginning of Time? Do you want this per user or over all users?

Comment: @laune `endDate` is a Java `Date` object, doesn't have to necessarily be midnight. `ClickEvent`s don't expire, at least not before `Product`s does. I am trying to achieve this per user.

Comment: I've proposed a solution "per user". The logic for determining the expiry date can/should be hidden in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a good idea to do this in steps

```
rule "interesting user/product"
when
  SessionClock( $now: time )
  Purchase( $uid: userId, $purchases: purchasedProducts )
  ClickEvent( userId == $uid, $pid: productId,
              event == "FAVORITE" )
  not ClickEvent( userId == $uid, productId == $pid,
                  event == "REMOVE_FAVORITE" )     
  Product( id == $pid, $endDate: endDate )
  eval( endDateIsToday( $now, $endDate ) )
then
end

rule "make Collection" extends "interesting user/product"
when
  not Collection( userId == $uid )
then
  insert( new Collection( $uid ) )
end

rule "fill Collection" extends "interesting user/product"
when
  $coll: Collection( userId == $uid, products not contains $pid )
then
  modify( $coll ){ addProduct( $pid ) }
end
```

A third rule, running with reduced salience, can do the notification.

**Edit** To clarify, `endDateIsToday` is a (DRL) function or static method. Collection is a class you need to define with a couple of fields: userId and set of product ids.

Comment: Are `endDateIsToday` and `addProduct` methods I should implement?

Comment: I've added a clarification.

Comment: I see. Is there any way I can achieve this with `collect`/`accumulate` instead of creating a new class `Collection`?

Comment: In the same way, without `endDateIsToday` method if it's not a must, but a "can/should"?

Comment: The requirements aren't for me to define. Omit the eval if you need to find any product, no matter when it expires.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I want to achieve the same functionality without a drl function. However without creating any new Java classes is more important (i.e. `Collection`)

Comment: Hmm, thinking a little more, if it is going to be per user, I need a new Java class. Or I can get a global collection of `$pid`s, am I right?

Comment: I don't see how we assure that user has not purchased that product (relation to `$purchases` or `purchasedProducts`)

Comment: Right, but adding the constraint that the product is  `this not memberOf $purchases` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: `$purchases` is not a list of `Product`s but a list of `PurchasedProduct`s. So I implemented `hashCode` and `equals` methods for both, and `eval ( $purchases not contains $pid )` works. Is this right?